# Rand entre números com vírgula

Tags: c++, random

Como gerar um numero `float` entre dois números?

Ex.: Um número aleatório entre -270.33 e -47.5.

Comment: Rand() trabalha com números inteiros... E não acho que esse tipo de comentário ajude para a solução do meu problema.

Comment: O que já tentou, e qual a dificuldade?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Antes de mais nada, a resposta do @Maniero já dá a solução que eu entendo ser a mais correta tecnicamente para o problema.

Postei esta resposta apenas como complemento ao comentário deixado na pergunta, especificamente sobre o `rand`, pois é perfeitamente possível usar o `rand()` para obter o resultado com ponto flutuante, usando matemática básica, se a faixa entre o mínimo e o máximo não for muito extensa:

```
res = min + rand() * (max - min) / RAND_MAX;
```

Veja funcionando no **[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/ild9Ea)**.

Considerando que `rand()` retorna um valor entre `0` e `RAND_MAX`, usamos a divisão por esta constante para que a faixa dos resultados seja distribuída de maneira homogênea, o que não é possível com o operador de resto/módulo ( `%` ), que tem mais probabilidade de retornar números menores, como usado em muitos exemplos "internet afora".

Esta solução não tem problema com o fato do `rand` usar inteiros, desde que a faixa entre o mínimo e o máximo seja proporcionalmente compatível com o `RAND_MAX` em relação às casas decimais desejadas.

Answer (score 8):

É só usar as funções da biblioteca padrão disponíveis para geração de números aleatórios:

```
random_device seed;
mt19937 gen(seed());
uniform_real_distribution<float> dis(-270.33, -47.5);
cout << dis(seed);
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/YCI7sB). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/neiygwxd-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Math/Decimal.cpp).

[Documentação](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random).

Answer (score 2):

Se você quer usar `rand`, e não uma das funções que suportam *floats* (como a resposta do Maniero), você vai precisar converter o resultado do `rand` num `float` (preferencialmente entre 0 e 1) antes de estender o valor para o *range* que você deseja.

Você pode fazer isso usando um pouco de manipulação de bits para que a representação em ponto flutuante do valor seja o que você deseja, como mostra o código abaixo (ou [rodando no Ideone](http://ideone.com/LoyExs))

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        int r = rand();
        // Assumindo que RAND_MAX seja pelo menos 2^32-1
        //printf("r = %d\n");

        // zera bit de sinal, expoente
        r = (r & 0x3FFFFFFF) | 0x3F800000; // zera bits de sinal de 
        //printf("r = %d\n");

        // gera numero entre 1 e 2
        float f = *((float *)&r);
        //printf("f = %f\n", f);

        // normaliza entre 0 e 1
        f = f - 1;
        //printf("f = %f\n", f);

        float min = -270.33f;
        float max = -47.5f;

        float fRand = min + (f * (max - min));
        printf("fRand = %f\n", fRand);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

O programa a seguir ilustra como sortear valores `double` usando a função `rand()`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define MIN    (-270.33f)
#define MAX    (-47.5f)


double randf( double min, double max )
{
    return min + (rand() / ( RAND_MAX / ( max - min) ) ) ;  
}


int main( int argc, char * argv[] )
{
    int i = 0;

    srand(time(NULL));

    for( i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        printf("%g ", randf( MIN, MAX ) );

    return 0;
}

/* fim-de-arquivo */
```